# IE 'about' says IE8 but css conditional only works for IE7, which IE version do I have?

Tags: css, internet-explorer, browser

I literally have to type in

```html
<!--[if IE 7]>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/ie8.css" />
<![endif]-->
```

to get my css hack to work for ie8. And yet when I click the 'abouts' tab in my IE browser, it clearly says IE8 version 8.0.6001. 18702.

I already reinstalled IE8 because I thought this issue was wierd but I still have to use the IE7 hack in order to get my IE8 only css to appear in my IE8 browser.

Is there something I can do to fix this? I have to talk to other developers and it is somewhat annoying not knowing exactly which IE version I have.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like your IE8 is running in Compatibility View, which causes it to render pages like IE7, including reading IE7 conditional comments.

Look for the button in your toolbar that looks like a torn page, click on that, and it should disable it and return you to IE8 rendering mode.